# Is there any way I can exclude paid search from channel graphics in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics and also Google Adwords. How can I adjust the graphics view to show traffic from all channels except paid search?

I can view each of them alone and sum up the results with calculator, but that is not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Create a segment](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3124493?hl=en) to show the data you want. For example, New Segment > Traffic Sources > Medium > [whatever channels you want]

Or, as pointed out in comments, Advanced Segment > Conditions > Source / Medium 'does not contain' google / cpc.

Comment: Thanks for help. Why did Google made it so hard to find? Or something wrong with me? Could not find for two years until ask on Stack...

Comment: A far more efficient way to remove PPC data would be to create an Advanced Segment > Conditions > Source / Medium ' does not contain' google / cpc. That will show all data except traffic from Adwords.

Comment: @Daveth3Cat That does sound better.

Comment: Sorry my comment sounded fairly rude - not my intention!

Comment: @Daveth3Cat Not at all, appreciate the comment. Added your (better) approach to my answer since it was already accepted.

Comment: @GDav no worries! I saw on your website that you'll be visiting brightonSEO - might see you there!